# Most of the time spotlight is showing nothing after upgrading to el capitan

Tags: macos, spotlight

I use spotlight a lot but after upgrading to el capitan most of the time its showing empty window.[image]

Its very annoying. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I too see this behaviour. Typing an extra letter or even removing a letter from the search term tends to fix the problem.

This appears to be a bug in OS X 10.11. Please can you provide [feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html). Every report helps!